# How can I write a function template that can accept either a stack or a queue?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, function-templates

I'm implementing four algorithms that are *completely* identical except for what data structure they use — two use `priority_queue`, one uses `stack`, and the last uses `queue`. They're relatively long, so I'd like to have just one function template that accepts the container type as a template argument and then have each algorithm call that template with the appropriate argument, like so:

```
template <class Container>
void foo(/* args */)
{
    Container dataStructure;
    // Algorithm goes here
}

void queueBased(/* args */)
{
    foo<queue<Item> >(/* args */);
}

void stackBased(/* args */)
{
    foo<stack<Item> >(/* args */);
}
```

I've managed to do just this with the `priority_queue`- and `stack`-based implementations, but I can't do the same for the `queue`-based algorithm because it uses a different name to access the foremost element (`front( )` instead of `top( )`). I know that I could specialize the template for this case, but then I'd have a big stretch of duplicated code (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

What's the best way to accomplish this? My first instinct was to create a wrapper class for queue that adds a `top( )` operation equivalent to `stack`'s, but I've been reading that subclassing STL classes is a no-no. How should I get this behavior, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a non-member `top` function overloaded on the type of the container adapter:

```
template <typename T>
T& top(std::stack<T>& s) { return s.top(); }

template <typename T>
T& top(std::queue<T>& q) { return q.front(); }

// etc.
```

If you actually use a different sequence container with the container adapters (via their `Sequence` template parameter), you'll need to modify the overloads appropriately to handle that.

It might just be more straightforward to use a sequence container (e.g. `std::vector`) directly rather than using one of the sequence adapters.

Comment: I'm implementing a set of search algorithms, so I need the specific ordering behavior of the adapters. (LIFO gives me a breadth-first search while FIFO gives me depth-first, e.g.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use partial specialization to select the right method:

```
template<class Container>
struct foo_detail {
  static typename Container::value_type& top(Container &c) { return c.top(); }
  static typename Container::value_type const& top(Container const &c) { return c.top(); }
};
template<class T, class Underlying>
struct foo_detail<std::queue<T, Underlying> > {
  typedef std::queue<T, Underlying> Container;
  static typename Container::value_type& top(Container &c) { return c.front(); }
  static typename Container::value_type const& top(Container const &c) { return c.front(); }
};

template<class Container>
void foo(/* args */)
{
    Container dataStructure;
    // Use foo_detail<Container>::top(dataStructure) instead of dataStructure.top().
    // Yes, I know it's ugly.  :(
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper around `std::queue` without using inheritance; in fact, inheritance would be the wrong tool here because you're trying to *decorate* a `queue` rather than *refining* or *extending* the `queue`.  Here's one possible implementation:

```
template <typename QueueType>
class QueueWrapper {
public:
    explicit QueueWrapper(const QueueType& q) : queue(q) {
        // Handled in initializer list
    }

    typedef typename QueueType::value_type value_type;

    value_type& top() {
        return queue.front();
    }
    const value_type& top() const {
        return queue.front();
    }

    void pop() {
        queue.pop();
    }
private:
    QueueType queue;
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`queue`, `priority_queue` and `stack` are all container adaptors; they are wrappers around an underlying container (by default, `deque` for `queue` and `stack` and `vector` for `priority_queue`).

Since `vector`, `deque` and `list` (the "real" container classes) share most of their methods, you could cut the middle man and use those classes instead.

And keep in mind that *public* inheritance is not a good idea for STL containers; *private* inheritance is okay (and probably what you want).

Answer (score -1):

`front()` and `top()` are specific to certain types of containers, but all STL containers support `*begin()`.

Comment: `std::priority_queue`, `std::stack`, and `std::queue` are not containers and none of them are iterable sequences.